# "without me" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, grammatical-case

I got confused while making a German sentence meaning:

> How you can enjoy your time **without me**?

How can I translate the without me part? Does it depend on the case, like "wie"? For example:

> Ich verstehe nichts, genau wie du.
>
> Sie ignorierte ihn, wie mich.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“Without me” is just “ohne mich”. *Ohne* is a preposition requiring the accusative case. Nothing special here.

Comment: I have also read "ohne ich" many times, there should be something special.

Comment: @Gigili Impossible ;p What you find googling "ohne ich" is *Ohne Ich, kein Wir* and sentences in which punctuations split *ohne* and *ich* or sentences in which the part behind *ohne* is a quote (missing quotation marks possible)

Comment: Well, Google is not a good dictionary @Em1. ;)

Comment: @ Gigili:  Nevertheless, Em1 is right.  _Ohne_ is always with accusative.

Answer (score 2):

"Wie kannst Du ohne mich Spaß haben?" or "Wie kannst Du Dich ohne mich amüsieren?", depending on how you want to translate "enjoy your time".